# Featureclass search failing in C++. But working in C#

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, c++

I need to perform search on a FeatureClass using ISpatialFilter for a given Point (x,y).
I wrote a program in C# to do that and its retrieving the features as expected. But the similar program in C++ is failing for some feature classes and working for some. I am wondering where it went wrong.

The below c++ code works fine for featureclass *cbsa*. But doesnt work for *BlockGroups*.

```cpp
    //Create Point
    IPointPtr ipPoint = NULL;
    ipPoint.CreateInstance(CLSID_Point);
    ipPoint->PutCoords( dX, xY);

    //Create Envelope
    IEnvelopePtr envelope(CLSID_Envelope);
    hr = ipPoint->get_Envelope(&envelope);

    //Open Feature Class
    IWorkspaceFactoryPtr pWorkspacefactory(CLSID_FileGDBWorkspaceFactory);
    IFeatureWorkspacePtr featureWorkspace;
    IWorkspacePtr workspace;
    hr = pWorkspacefactory->OpenFromFile(CComBSTR(gdbpath,0,&workspace);
    featureWorkspace = workspace;
    IFeatureClassPtr featureClass;
    hr = featureWorkspace->OpenFeatureClass(CComBSTR("CensusBGroups"),&featureClass);

    // Set ISpatialFilter Properties
    BSTR shapeFieldName;
    hr = featureClass->get_ShapeFieldName(&shapeFieldName);

    ISpatialFilterPtr spatialFilter(CLSID_SpatialFilter);
    spatialFilter->putref_Geometry(envelope);
    spatialFilter->put_SpatialRel(esriSpatialRelIntersects);
    spatialFilter->put_GeometryField(shapeFieldName);

    // Search
    IFeatureCursorPtr featureCursor;
    featureClass->Search(spatialFilter, false, &featureCursor); // featurecursor doesnt contain any featueres
    IFeaturePtr feature;

    // Get First Feature
    hr = featureCursor->NextFeature(&feature); //feature is null
    IFieldsPtr totalfields;
    hr = feature->get_Fields(&totalfields);
```

Comment: Hi, What is the shape type of "cbsa" and "BlockGroups"?

Comment: Both are of type **Polygon**

Comment: Does the spatial reference of the envelope match that of the featureclass being searched?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it works fine in C#, however, Point is 1 dimension geometry which doesn't  contain valid extent. So, I recommended to use Point geometry instead of using Envelope geometry. Here is the sample code, and also I fixed some part of code which was verbose.

```
//Create Point
IPointPtr ipPoint(CLSID_Point);
ipPoint->PutCoords( dX, xY);

//Open Feature Class
IWorkspaceFactoryPtr pWorkspacefactory(CLSID_FileGDBWorkspaceFactory);
IFeatureWorkspacePtr featureWorkspace;
IWorkspacePtr workspace;
hr = pWorkspacefactory->OpenFromFile(CComBSTR(gdbpath),0,&workspace);
featureWorkspace = workspace;
IFeatureClassPtr featureClass;
hr = featureWorkspace->OpenFeatureClass(CComBSTR(L"CensusBGroups"),&featureClass);

// Set ISpatialFilter Properties
BSTR shapeFieldName;
hr = featureClass->get_ShapeFieldName(&shapeFieldName);

//Use Point geometry directly for SpatialFilter
ISpatialFilterPtr spatialFilter(CLSID_SpatialFilter);
spatialFilter->putref_Geometry(ipPoint);
spatialFilter->put_SpatialRel(esriSpatialRelIntersects);
//If the search origin is Point and search destination is Polygon,
//you can also use esriSpatialRelWithin
//spatialFilter->put_SpatialRel(esriSpatialRelWithin);
spatialFilter->put_GeometryField(shapeFieldName);

// Search
IFeatureCursorPtr featureCursor;
featureClass->Search(spatialFilter, false, &featureCursor); // featurecursor doesnt contain any featueres
IFeaturePtr feature;

// Get First Feature
hr = featureCursor->NextFeature(&feature); //feature is null
IFieldsPtr totalfields;
hr = feature->get_Fields(&totalfields);
```

Hope this helps you.